# Unable to execute queries on Hive server 2 through JDBC

Tags: maven, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am trying to perform single tuple insertions on Hive Server 2 using JDBC for testing. Although I am able to such operations without issue through beeline client while connecting to `jdbc:hive2://` on the server, I am unable to replicate the same using JDBC.

The concerned code snippet in a file **TestDAO.java** is as follows:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into table test_table select ?, ? from dummy");
ps.setInt(1, test.getRoll());
ps.setString(2, test.getName());

System.out.println("Name = " + test.getName() + ", Roll = " + test.getRoll());

returnValue = ps.executeUpdate();    // Line 22
```

While executing the code, an exception is encountered:

```
Starting...
jdbc:hive2://7.224.118.49:10000/acaddwh
Connection obtained!
Name = Inserted User, Roll = 120
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.HdfsAdmin.getEncryptionZoneForPath(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/EncryptionZone;
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:277)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeUpdate(HiveStatement.java:390)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HivePreparedStatement.java:117)
    at in.ac.iitkgp.acaddwh.dao.TestDAO.saveDim(TestDAO.java:22)
    at in.ac.iitkgp.acaddwh.service.etl.TestHiveLoad.load(TestHiveLoad.java:34)
    at in.ac.iitkgp.acaddwh.service.etl.TestHiveLoad.main(TestHiveLoad.java:71)
in.ac.iitkgp.acaddwh.exception.LoadException
    at in.ac.iitkgp.acaddwh.service.etl.TestHiveLoad.load(TestHiveLoad.java:44)
    at in.ac.iitkgp.acaddwh.service.etl.TestHiveLoad.main(TestHiveLoad.java:71)
Load,1,120,Data is invalid
```

I have given "rwx" permissions to all tables within the database using:

```
hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive/warehouse/acaddwh.db/test_table
```

However, that didn't change anything. I am attaching further info which might be relevant to the question.

---

> Version info: Hive 0.12.0-cdh5.1.0

I started the server by executing the following:

```
./hive --service hiveserver2 10000 &
```

This is the complete list of dependencies in my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.1-cdh5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-cdh5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.1-cdh5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-cdh5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

What might be the issue and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

After a number of trial-and-errors, I was able to connect and execute INSERT, LOAD DATA, SELECT queries successfully using my Java application by starting the hive server using:

```
hiveserver2
```

instead of

```
./hive --service hiveserver2 10000 &
```

Additionally, to have the server running without interrupting on logout, I am currently using the following to start the server:

```
nohup hiveserver2 &
```

Answer (score 0):

hadoop/ HDFS do not support any update.

Comment: Just to check, I changed **ps.executeUpdate();** to **ps.execute();**, and it still didn't work.

 I'm trying to perform an insertion of a new row, and the same query executes while using beeline client or hive embedded client; just not through my Java code.
Moreover, SELECT queries are also not working through JDBC.